# How to CHANGE the VALUE of a SELECT FORM using a switch and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi everyone I'm making a timer and i have an issue.
i'm trying to speed up and down the timer using a select form but that doesn't work can someone explain where i'm wrong please

certainly at the end with the switch

this is my code :

html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

`    :
     :

```
<input id="reset" type="button" value="reset">
<input id="pauseButton" type="button" value="Pause">
<input id="reprendreButton" type="button" value="Reprendre">

<form>
<select id="bla" >
<option value="x05">x05</option>
<option value="x1" selected>x1</option>
<option value="x2">x2</option>
<option value="x4">x4</option>
</select>
</form>
```

`

javascript

```
<script>





var timer = {
    totalSeconds: 0,
    start: function () {
        var mat = this;

        this.interval = setInterval(function () {
            mat.totalSeconds += 1;

            $("#heure").text(Math.floor(mat.totalSeconds / 3600));
            $("#min").text(Math.floor(mat.totalSeconds / 60 % 60));
            $("#sec").text(parseInt(mat.totalSeconds % 60));
        }, 1000);
    },





    pause: function () {

        this.interval =  clearInterval(this.interval);
        this.interval =  delete this.interval;

    },

    x05: function () {

        // this.interval = this.totalSeconds += 2;
        var mat = this;

        this.interval = setInterval(function () {
            mat.totalSeconds += 1/2;

            $("#heure").text(Math.floor(mat.totalSeconds / 3600));
            $("#min").text(Math.floor(mat.totalSeconds / 60 % 60));
            $("#sec").text(parseInt(mat.totalSeconds % 60));
        }, 1000);


    },

    x1: function () {

        // this.interval = this.totalSeconds += 2;
        var mat = this;

        this.interval = setInterval(function () {
            mat.totalSeconds += 1;

            $("#heure").text(Math.floor(mat.totalSeconds / 3600));
            $("#min").text(Math.floor(mat.totalSeconds / 60 % 60));
            $("#sec").text(parseInt(mat.totalSeconds % 60));
        }, 1000);


    },

    x2: function () {

       // this.interval = this.totalSeconds += 2;
        var mat = this;

        this.interval = setInterval(function () {
            mat.totalSeconds += 2;

            $("#heure").text(Math.floor(mat.totalSeconds / 3600));
            $("#min").text(Math.floor(mat.totalSeconds / 60 % 60));
            $("#sec").text(parseInt(mat.totalSeconds % 60));
        }, 1000);


    },

    x4: function () {

        // this.interval = this.totalSeconds += 2;
        var mat = this;

        this.interval = setInterval(function () {
            mat.totalSeconds += 4;

            $("#heure").text(Math.floor(mat.totalSeconds / 3600));
            $("#min").text(Math.floor(mat.totalSeconds / 60 % 60));
            $("#sec").text(parseInt(mat.totalSeconds % 60));
        }, 1000);


    },

    Reprendre: function () {

        this.interval = !this.interval;
        this.interval = this.start();
    },

    reset: function () {

      // clearInterval(this.interval);

        this.interval = this.totalSeconds -= this.totalSeconds +=1 ;


    }

};

timer.start();


$('#pauseButton').click(function () { timer.pause(); });
$('#reprendreButton').click(function () { timer.Reprendre(); });
$('#reset').click(function () { timer.reset(); });


$(document).ready(function(){
    switch($('#bla' ).val()) {

        case 'x05':
           /* $('#bla').click(function () { timer.x05(); }); */
            break;
        case 'x1':
          /*  $('#bla').click(function () { timer.x1(); }); */
            break;
        case 'x2':
           /* $('#bla').click(function () { timer.x2(); });  */
            break;
        case 'x4':
          /*  $('#bla').click(function () { timer.x4(); });  */
            break;
        default:
        //
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only checking the value of `#bla` when the document is ready.  You need to do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#bla' ).on('change', function(){
     switch($(this.val())) {
        case 'x05':
             timer.x05(); 
            break;
        case 'x1':
           timer.x1();
            break;
        case 'x2':
             timer.x2();  
            break;
        case 'x4':
            timer.x4(); 
            break;
        default:
            //
            break;
      }
   });
});
```

Here you would be checking for the value of `#bla` when the select box changes.  Then running your functions once you uncommented them.  I'm not sure if the rest of you're code is working but this should run the switch whenever the value in the select is changed.

I've made a CodePen, this is how I write JS so it was easier for me to work out what might be going on:

https://codepen.io/dammeul/pen/GZQpqZ?editors=1010

Currently the time works and such and but it only pauses once, after starting the interval again it doesn't seem to want to pause.  Though it resets fine, and I'm not sure about the speed controls.  Have a look, hopefully this should get you going for a full fix for it all.

Comment: thanks for your answer but  it's still doesn't work have any idea why ?

Comment: Sorry, was late when I answered this!  I've made some edits, basically all you were doing was running the switch whenever it changed and then initialising the click event which would run the function when you click on `#bla`.  What you need it to do is run the function whenever `#bla` changes.  As long as your timer function works correctly and you are hitting `.x05` etc. then I think this should work!

Comment: I've made some edits and also added a code pen for you to have a look at it with most of your code working, though it's wrote how I write my JS but using you're code obviously!  Some bits don't work, but hopefully I've fixed enough to get you started.